# Using references or pointers to perform a Deposit method?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm having trouble understanding passing references and pointers. I've gone over it so many times in my head but just can't seem to click with it, and I think it's what I need to use here, to actually modify the value in the Account object.

Are there any surefire simple ways to understand them? And how would they apply to this fairly simple scenario?

main code:

```
if (transactionMenuChoice == 2)
{
cout << "________________________________________________" << endl;
cout << "//TRANSACTION MENU - WITHDRAWAL" << endl;
cout << "//CURRENT CUSTOMER: " << allCustomers.at(customerIndex).getName() << endl;
cout << "//CURRENT ACCOUNT: " << allCustomers.at(customerIndex).getAccounts().at(accountIndex).getAccountNum() << " (" << allCustomers.at(customerIndex).getAccounts().at(accountIndex).getType() << ")" << endl;
cout << "||Withdraw how much?" << endl;
cout << "||£" << endl;

int d;
cin >> d;   

allCustomers.at(customerIndex).getAccounts().at(accountIndex).removeFromBalance(d);
}
```

from my Account.cpp:

```
void Account::removeFromBalance(double d) 
{
    balance -= d;
}
```

Comment: The example looks to me like it should work without any explicit reference passing or so on. It also looks like it should be implemented like it is. However, the data structure `allCustomers` should return references from `at()`. There is no code for this, so you can't get more than a guess.

Comment: Assuming `allCustomers` and `getAccounts()` are `std::vector`, then `at()` returns a reference.  You pass in a double by value (using copy semantics).  This should work just fine.

Comment: `allCustomers` is indeed `std::vector`, must be my syntax elsewhere then.

Comment: You need to show us your testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to the difference between value references and pointer references?  A pointer is the address of a thing, not the thing itself.  Your address is a 'pointer' to your mailbox, but not the mailbox itself.  In your removeFromBalance function you are passing 'd' by value (not as a pointer).  C++ object syntax can sometimes muddy the water since you will see '.' notation to call member function on actual (when you have an object) and '->' notation used to call a member function when you have a pointer to an object.

Comment: Why does this "muddy the water"? Think of `a->b` as equivalent to `(*a).b` (which it is) and all becomes very clear.

Comment: I think that for people just learning it can be confusing to have two way to access a member.  Still you make a very good point.

Comment: It's only one way to access a member.